# Finding strings from a python list in other python list's values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists in python and want to check if the string values of list1 are present in any part of string values of list2. If all are present print a successful message.

The lists are:

```
list1 = ['star', 'moon', 'sun', 'kat']

list2 = ['This is a star', 'moonlight', '-sun', 'kat-trade', 'amaze']
```

In above case a successful message should be printed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `all` with `any`:

```
print(all(any(i in x for x in list2) for i in list1))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `join`:

```
all([s in ' '.join(list2) for s in list1 ])
# True
```